# How to highlight active link in bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are 3 in-line buttons in a website that is based on bootstrap version 3:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="page1.php">button 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="page2.php">button 2</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="page3.php">button 3</a>
</div>
```

I want to highlight whichever a tag is active, I tried the following jquery code

```
$(".btn-group > a").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

but it doesn't work, I even tried the following code

```
$(".btn-group > a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

above code seems to work, but the issue is the link stopped working altogether. it just stays the same page and only highlight buttons.

Any guidance how I can achieve it?

I would like to do it with a tag instead of  tag, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/3mDRY/

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out. actually, the fiddle you shared is similar to what I'm trying to achieve with just one slight change. 

In your fiddle, the <a> tag is being prevented from opening a new link, but I want that it allows the new link to be opened but still apply selected css class as shown in your fiddle.